# Error in Success callbackId:というエラー

Tags: javascript, monaca

> Error in Success callbackId: Camera463 : TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new NCMB.File(fileName, byteCharacters, "image/png")')

というエラーが出るのですが、意味を教えてください。
niftyのモバイルバックエンドを利用しています。

下記がコードの抜粋になります。

JavaScript

```
function snapPicture () {
        navigator.camera.getPicture (onSuccess, onFail,
            { quality: 50, destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL});

        //成功した際に呼ばれるコールバック関数
        function onSuccess (imageData) {
            var byteCharacters = toBlob(imageData);
            var NCMBFile = new NCMB.File(fileName, byteCharacters, "image/png");
            NCMBFile.save().then(function() {
              //NCMBサーバーからファイルをダウンロード
              var getFile =  new NCMB.File(fileName);
              var image_canvas = document.getElementById("showImage");
              getFile.fetchImgSource(image_canvas);
            },
            function(error) {
            　// The file either could not be read, or could not be saved to NCMB.
              alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### エラーの意味

> Error in Success callbackId: Camera463 :

この部分はMonacaというか内部のCordovaが表示している部分で、どこでエラーが起きたかを示しています。が、これはとりあえず置いておいて次に行きます。

> TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new NCMB.File(fileName, byteCharacters, "image/png")')

これがJavascriptのエラーです。 `xxx is not a constructor` というのは、コンストラクタではないxxxという値がコンストラクタとして呼び出された、ということを表します。この場合、 `NCMB.File` はコンストラクタのはずですが、実際には `undefined` だったということになります。

undefinedが意図せずして現れるのは、存在しない変数・プロパティを参照したときが多いです。

### 原因

ニフティクラウド mobile backend の Javascript SDK は去年の9月にVersion2が公開されました。

[SDKガイド (JavaScript) : Version2に伴う変更点 | ニフティクラウド mobile backend](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/sdkguide/javascript/versionChangeDescription.html)

[`NCMB.File` コンストラクタ](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/assets/sdk_doc/javascript/jsdoc_1.2.6/symbols/NCMB.File.html)は Version1 系のAPIで、現在の最新である Version2 系には存在しないものです。そのため、Version2のSDKで実行するとそのようなエラーになるかと思います。

Version1のサポートは 2016/3/16 で終了するようなのでVersion2に乗り換えたいところですが、Version2のマニュアルでは[「ブラウザやMonacaでのファイルアップロードは今後対応予定です。」](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/filestore/basic_usage_javascript.html)とあり、現時点でMonacaからファイルストアを利用したい場合はVersion1を利用する必要があるようです。

Version1のSDKは現在SDKダウンロードページの一番下からダウンロードが可能です。こちらからダウンロードしなおしてお試しください。

[イントロダクション (JavaScript) : SDKダウンロード | ニフティクラウド mobile backend](http://mb.cloud.nifty.com/doc/current/introduction/sdkdownload_javascript)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
SDKが原因なのですね。
ご説明の通りやってみようと思います。